# Function scope incorrect output

Tags: c++, c, function, scope

When i run this code i get the answer as 5 but i don't understand how this works
In my own understanding this should be an infinite loop
because the value of number  will never change as its inside of a function scope
This function gives an output of 5 and the for loop runs only once 
I need to understand how the conditions are satisfied here.

```
#include <stdio.h>      

int num=7;      

int r();      

int main()
{    
    for(r();r();r())    
    {
        printf("%d",r());
        return 0;
    }
}

int r()
{
    return num--;
}
```

Comment: Indent/format your code properly, you return inside the loop, can't be infinite at all.

Comment: There's only one `num`, and it's certainly not in one function's scope only.

Comment: `return 0;` just ends the main function immediately when it's reached, so it will not loop again.

Comment: Thank you for your advice but i am still confused about return. I have read on some answer "return in an inner function (not main) will terminate immediately the execution of the specific function returning the given result to the calling function.
So how does retrun work here

Comment: "So how does return work here" -- Well, you just explained it. What don't you understand?

Comment: the point about return 0 terminating the loop which is inside main

Answer (score 1):

What happen to `num` during the execution ?

```
num = 7;
r(); // first argument of for, init nothing → return 7, then num = 6
r(); // second argument of for → return 6, then num = 5
// third argument is done at the end of for, not now
printf("%d",r()); // execute r() → return 5, then num = 4, but print 5
return 0; // exit the current function or the process if it's in the main function
```

For information:

num--; // return num then decrease num
--num; // decrease num then return num

Same things for the ++ operator.

Comment: I know that after printf("%d",r()); the function updates and then checks the condition how is the condition false so as to terminate the loop. is it because of return 0;

Comment: There is the `continue` keyword to start the next loop, and the `break` keywoard to exit all loops.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say we have this `for` loop, where `A`, `B`, `C` and `D` are valid expressions:

```
for (A; B; C)
{
    D;
}
```

This is equivalent to the following `while` loop:

```
A;
while (B)
{
    D;
    C;
}
```

Since `D` in your loop is a `printf` call followed by a `return` statement, the loop will iterate only once (and `C` is not executed), then return from the `main` function which will terminate the program.

And as for why you get `5` printed, it's because `r` is called twice before you call `printf`, decreasing it from `7` twice to `5`.

If you *unroll* the loop, it will be like

```
r();  // Initialization in `for` loop
r();  // Condition in `for` loop
printf(...);
return 0;  // Terminates the program
```

Answer (score 0):

If you indent your code properly:

```
include <stdio.h>

int num = 7;

int r()
{
    return num--;
}

int main()
{    
    for(r(); r(); r()) {
        printf("%d", r());    
        return 0;    
    }
}
```

you'll see that it can't be an infinite loop, because you return from it after printing for the first time.

Changes to local variables are not seen from outside thze function, but you variable `num` is a global variable. Both `main` and `r` see the same instance of this global variable.

As to why the answer is 5, rewrite the for loop as equivalent `while` loop:

```
int main()
{   
    r();                            /* init */
    while (r()) {                   /* condition */
        printf("%d", r());    
        return 0;
        r();                        /* update */
    }
}
```

The function `r` returns the original value of `num`. The decrement happens afterv the return. (Well, it doesn't, of course: The compiler makes a copy, decrements and returns the copy.)